# Python - Convert Money values in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataset containing a column for the prices of each soccer player, and i would like to convert the values with 'K' to 'M' so i can sort it.
column name : Values
dataset : fifa
example :

```
         Values :
          €21M
          €2K
          €3.2M
          €18.3K
```

I would like it to be :

```
          Values :
          €21M
          €0.002M
          €0.0032M
          €0.0183M
```

Comment: strip the last character for each value and if its equals to 'K' divide it by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this dataframe:

```
   Values
0    €21M
1     €2K
2   €3.2M
3  €18.3K
```

Then:

```py
df["Values"] = df["Values"].str.replace(
    r"([\d.]+)K", lambda g: str(float(g.group(1)) / 1000) + "M", regex=True
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Values
0      €21M
1   €0.002M
2     €3.2M
3  €0.0183M
```